# download base64 as PDF seting a name for it

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf, url, lightning-community, base64

I'm trying to download a PDF file and I wish to give a name to this file and a extension.

Here is what I did:

Component:

`<aura:component
    implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
    access="global">
    <lightning:button variant="base" label="Download PDF" title="Download PDF" onclick="{! c.getPDF }"/>
</aura:component>`

JS Controller:

```
({
getPDF : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.parseBase64toFile();
}
})
```

JS Helper:

```
({
parseBase64toFile : function() {
    var base64 = 'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
      'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
      'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
      'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
      'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
      'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
      'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
      'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
      'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
      'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
      'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
      'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
      'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G'
    var url = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + base64;
    var urlEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL');

    console.log('url');
    console.log(url);
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": url
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
})
```

[image: the name is 'download' as default and there is no extension]

Answer (score 4):

If you change the way your component works rather than using a `force:navigateToURL` event and instead put your octet stream into an anchor tag, you can use the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) attribute on the `<a>` tag to specify a filename and extension.

```
<a download="myfile.pdf" href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,...">Download PDF</a>
```

Unfortunately the [data URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) does not have a mechanism built in for specifying the file name and extension. Also refer to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955860/filename-of-downloaded-file-in-dataapplication-octet-stream).

The other possible approach is setting the HTTP headers for your URL.